# Looking up a value from a set of duplicates to be assigned to a unique value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a project where I have a table A with unique serial numbers and a separate table B with duplicates of serial numbers and customer locations. I am trying to pair the customer locations from table B to each unique serial number that I have listed in table A.

Originally I was trying to use the `LOOKUPVALUE` function but I continued to get the error "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected".

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the same serial number in multiple departments, so the `LOOKUPVALUE` function doesn't know which department you want to return in that case.

Try using the following to identify which serial numbers are associated with multiple departments.

```
LocationCount =
    COUNTROWS(
        CALCULATETABLE(
            VALUES('Asset List'[Customer_Department]),
            FILTER(
                 'Asset List',
                 'Asset List'[Asset_Serial_Num] = 'Usage Calculations'[Serial Number]         )
        )
    )
```

You should be able to filter `LocationCount > 1`.

---

If you just want to pick one value, then you can use `MAX` or `MIN` instead of `LOOKUPVALUE`. E.g.

```
Location =
        CALCULATE(
            MAX('Asset List'[Customer_Department]),
            FILTER(
                'Asset List',
                'Asset List'[Asset_Serial_Num] = 'Usage Calculations'[Serial Number]
            )
        )
```

`FIRSTNONBLANK` and `LASTNONBLANK` would probably also work.

Comment: The serial numbers are unique to the department it belongs to, the problem is there are multiple entries of x serial numbers matches to y department.

Comment: `LOOKUPVALUE` can handle that just fine as long as there is only possible value to return. I'll bet there's at least one serial number that is in multiple departments (even if there shouldn't be). Please see my edit for how to find the culprit.

Comment: I tried out your edit and got an error.

"The expression contains multiple columns, but only a single column can be used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression."

Comment: Sorry. That needs to go in a FILTER function. I've fixed it above.

Comment: Okay, the edit to figure out which serials are duplicates worked. After looking through which ones are I don't really have a way around that. Is there such a way that my original plan could work by listing the first or last location it finds? They technically should be the same regardless if they are duplicates or not.

I appreciate all of the help by the way!

Comment: Just decide how you want to choose. Max/Min First/Last. See above.